# How can i add a property to a form to set how many colors to use and on how many lines?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of the new form i added:

```
Color[] colors;
```

Then i created a property for the Colors:

```
public Color[] ColorLines
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colors;
            }
            set
            {
                this.colors = value;
            }
        }
```

Then i have this paint event:

```
private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), this.ClientRectangle);
            GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

            int visibleLines = 0; 

            Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 16);

            for (int i = m_text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {

                Point pt = new Point((int)((this.ClientSize.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(m_text[i], m_font).Width) / 2),
                    (int)(m_scrollingOffset + this.ClientSize.Height - (m_text.Length - i) * m_font.Size));
                if ((pt.Y + this.Font.Size > 0) && (pt.Y < this.Height))
                {
                    path.AddString(m_text[i], m_font.FontFamily, (int)m_font.Style, m_font.Size,
                        pt, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

                    visibleLines++;
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(colors[i % 2]), pt);
            }
            if ((visibleLines == 0) && (m_scrollingOffset < 0))
            {
                m_scrollingOffset = (int)this.Font.SizeInPoints * m_text.Length;
            }           
            int topSizeWidth = (int)(this.Width * m_topPartSizePercent / 100.0f);
            path.Warp(
                new PointF[4] 
                { 
                    new PointF((this.Width - topSizeWidth) / 2, 0),
                    new PointF(this.Width - (this.Width - topSizeWidth) / 2, 0),
                    new PointF(0, this.Height),
                    new PointF(this.Width, this.Height)
                },
                new RectangleF(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height),
                null,
                WarpMode.Perspective
                );
            e.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), path);
            path.Dispose();
        }
```

In the paint event i added:

```
Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 16);
```

And DrawString to color the lines:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(colors[i % 2]), pt);
```

And i use it in form1 constructor like this:

```
m_scroller.ColorLines = new Color[] { Color.Red,Color.Black };
```

The problem is that in form1 i can add how many colors that i want: Color.Red only or Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Green and so on...

And according to how many Colors i add in form1 i need to change the number of lines to color in the new form on the line:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(colors[i % 2]), pt);
```

If on form1 i use two colors then i need to set here to 2. If one color then to 1. If five colors then to 5.

How can i add to the same property of colors also that i will have to set the number of lines to color ? ( or maybe i need to make a new property for the lines numbers ? )

Comment: This may be a dumb question from my part, but why don't you use skinning/theme/project color pallets to restrict the colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you want... You can overload your new form constructor (let's call it Form2) - add new constructor with parameters:

In Form2:

```
private Color[] _colors;

public Form2(Color[] colors)
{
   _colors = colors;
}

...
// Also you can count colors instead of sending their number to second form
e.Graphics.DrawString(m_text[i], drawFonts1, new SolidBrush(_colors[i % _colors.Count]), pt);
```

And in form1, when you open your second form, you can do:

```
m_scroller.ColorLines = new Color[] { Color.Red,Color.Black };
...
var newForm = new Form2(m_scroller.ColorLines);
newForm.ShowDialog();
```